# EF code first migration

Tags: entity-relationship, entity-framework-migrations

I have followed below steps to create database using code first approach.

1. Create classes
2. Launch package manager
3. Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName -MyDb
4. Made change in Model class
5. execute 'Update-Database -Verbose'
6. Change was reflected in the database table

Now I connect to the database and delete table.  When I am executing 'Update-Database -Verbose' command, my expectation was it will create table again but its failing with below error message.

```
    PM> Update-Database -Force
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending code-based migrations.
Applying automatic migration: 201308221453295_AutomaticMigration.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
ClientConnectionId:d07c8463-88f6-44fa-a242-fe0da2c36f31
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

Can anyone help?  How can I create table again using code first approach?
```

Regards,
Hemant Shelar

Comment: Enable Migrations in your project and folow its related articles like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's a system table in the database that holds all the run migrations, so rerunning `Update-Database` shouldn't do anything. Unless you've changed your model in your project causing an Automatic Migration, where you haven't explicitly created the migration and Entity Framework is trying to match the database to the models.

As Raphaël mentioned, it's code first. You shouldn't be modifying the tables directly if you want to manage it through code first. If you really want to do this, you need to remove the migration from the `__MigrationHistory` system table so Entity Framework doesn't think the migration has run. Or use the `Update-Database -Target:[migration target here]` to downgrade/revert a database through the commandlet.